# C program that executes bash commands inside xterm with execl

Tags: c, linux, exec, system-calls

I have a command that execute well in the normal terminal on Linux:

```
xterm -e bash -c "some commands"
```

I want to execute the above command using c program execXX system calls. I try to use the following codes but it gives me a normal xterm window.

```
execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "/usr/bin/xterm -e bash -c \"some commands\"", NULL);
```

Is there any way I can execute the above command using execXX system calls? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call it like:

```
execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "/usr/bin/xterm", "-e", "bash", "-c", "some commands", (void*)NULL);
```

The convention is to let the first argument be the same as the path to the program. If you have spaces in the arguments, it will be the same effect as calling `xterm 'something with spaces'` instead of `xterm something with spaces`.

Comment: Note that the last parameter should be cast to `void *`. `NULL` is otherwise just 0 and since it's a variadic function, it might push a zero with a smaller size than a pointer.

Comment: @Shahbaz, took a second until I understood what you meant. While technically true, I think most ABIs would make this a non-issue. I think there must be tons of code where NULL is not cast to (void*). But you are correct as far as I understand.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really a non-issue. I haven't seen it go wrong, but unless the compiler specifically knows that `execl` expects `(void *)NULL` in the end (which I think gcc _does_), there is no way it can know that it should push 64bit zeros instead of 32bits (in case of a 64-bit architecture for example). That means on non-gcc compilers and on non-standard library functions (unless you put the right gcc `__attribute__`), this could very easily become an issue.

Comment: @Shahbaz, hm, yes. I think GCC is nice and expands NULL to __nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

A possible tangent: is there any reason why you need these to run specifically within `xterm`?  If you just want to run some shell commands, then running them within `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` would be more natural, and probably more reliable.